# Table align RIGHT within VML textbox???

Tags: html, email, background, outlook, vml

Does anyone know how to align a table right within a VML textbox? Left and center work fine but Right seems to get ignored....

Heres and example of the code

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png');" background="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" height="92" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:92px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->

            <div>
                <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FF00FF" align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"> | This is test text | </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `<div>` to `width:100%;`. If that doesn't fix it, put a 100% width table in there, nest and align the child (your desired content) within that.

Example:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png');" background="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" height="92" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:92px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->

            <div style="width:100%;">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right">
                    <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#FF00FF" align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"> | This is test text | </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>

            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No sorry this didn't work! I need to be able to align the tables so I can place two table next to each other, one left(works fine) but the right align gets completely ignored!

Comment: Why not just put two `<td>`s in the same row then? Aligning is only good if you want it the content to overflow (pop down) when the screen width shrinks (they can't fit). Using 2 `<td>`s will ensure they always remain next to each other. Also, if you want to align, you should align them both in the same direction. Most clients are driven by the parent `<td align="left">`, so putting conflicting directions in the floating/aligned tables themselves will produce inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, late coming to the party...

you need an extra div with align="right" before you table & contents. VML textbox ignores align on tables for some reason.

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#DDDDDD" style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png');" background="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" height="92" valign="top"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:92px;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/XCnBXwP.png" color="#7bceeb" />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->

       <div>
            <div align="right">
                <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FF00FF" align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;"> | This is test text | </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
       </div>

      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/8080/table-align-right-within-vml-textbox/)