# Text align CENTER within VML textbox?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, vml

I'm making email template and need to place text in center of the image. I've tried this solution ([Table align RIGHT within VML textbox???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985461/table-align-right-within-vml-textbox)), but my image can't be displayed.
Here is my code:

```
<div align="center" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="80%" style="width:45em;padding:0;margin:0;border-spacing:0;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom" height="300" background="https://parentingwalkthrough.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/EmailHeader_Image.jpg"  style="background-size: 100% 100%;height:15em;text-align: center;">
                  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 700px; height: 250px;" src="https://parentingwalkthrough.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/EmailHeader_Image.jpg" />
                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 230px;">
                    <v:fill opacity="0%" color="#111111"  />
                    <v:textbox inset="250px,180px,0px,0px" style="mso-text-scale: 26px; mso-fit-text-to-shape: false; ">
                      <![endif]-->
                      <div align="right">
                        <h1 style="color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 2em;margin-bottom: 1em;">|||Some text in caption here|||</h1>
                        </div>
                      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:fill>
                  </v:rect>
                  </v:image>
                  <![endif]-->
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It displays good for some certain Outlook window size, but how can i fix the text horizontaly in the center???

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about horizontal center then you need to put table with centered cell inside `<v:textbox>` tag. Like this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"><v:fill type="tile" src="/path/to/image" color="#343434" /><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0"><![endif]-->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="800" align="center" style="text-align: center;">Centered text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!--[if gte mso 9]></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

The `background` property is not supported in Outlook as it is hown in the markup (only when there is a URL):

```
<td valign="bottom" height="300" background="https://parentingwalkthrough.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/EmailHeader_Image.jpg"  style="background-size: 100% 100%;height:15em;text-align: center;">
```

You can specify a background color, but not an image URL.

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Comment: So I used VML to show image in Outlook. I've copied it from somewhere, but i can't figure out how to put the text in the center of that image.